# Is it possible to show all friends in a Facebook Request Dialog via iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK v3.17.

I want to allow the user to invite multiple friends to my app, without using the Invitable Friends API (I don't have a Canvas app).  Wondering if its actually possible to see ALL of a user's friends in the multi-friend selector.

My code is...

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                              message:@"Download dis app now, kiiiiiiiiiid!"
                                                title:@"Ahoy!"
                                           parameters:nil
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                              }];
```

I'm not passing in any parameters, and in the [documentation for Request Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1), it states, in reference to the parameter `filter` (which I haven't set)...

> This controls the set of friends someone sees if a multi-friend selector is shown. If left empty, the multi-friend selector will display all of the user's Facebook friends.

This does not happen.  It always shows only about 6 users, and defaults to people who have already used the app.  If I set `filter` to @"app_non_users", and pass the parameters dictionary, it only picks 6 users (seemingly at random) who have not used the app, not all of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find an answer to this? if you did can you please share. i have the same problem and cant find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no mechanism in the API to do what you're asking for. The user can always use the search field to add specific friends by name. In general, we've found that having 200+ friends show up in a list that you have to scroll through is not an ideal user experience.

Comment: At least it should display some 20 people if not all and load more on scroll. On iPhone 6 and 6 plus half the screen remains empty. Also nowhere in docs its mentioned to display limited(6) friends only. The example image in docs itself has more friends displayed than 6.

Comment: I think you should assume that this is an experience we are testing, and will continually be iterating on.

Comment: @MingLi, I guess you guys are still iterating :) I'm seeing a similar issue on a web integration and if you consider this a data point, then it is annoying :)
I see 'All Friends' in the filter and 6 suggested friends and no way to indicate that the rest are searchable. Not asking for much, just that you add something that indicates that the user needs to use the search field to find other friends.