# Facebook Android SDK apprequests dialog: Multiple friend selector shows only six friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-requests

My question maybe termed as a duplicate for the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315781/is-it-possible-to-show-all-friends-in-a-facebook-request-dialog-via-ios-sdk) but i am posting it as a new question coz that is for the iOS sdk and maybe someone working with the android SDK may know a solution.

i am using the apprequest dialog and the multi friend selector shown on the my native android app shows a 'suggested friends' list that contains rightly only the users that are not using the app. But the list is only 6 items long which are randomly chosen. The rest of the friends are searchable from the search box above.

[attached screenshot[image: ]]

i want the whole list there or at least a paginated list in some order so a person can go through it and select the friends he wants to send the requests to. Something like that is done on the web based SDKs i think. Can this be done on the mobile? Or is it by design just a six friends list?